# Mail merge in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

I'm looking for a way to do a mail merge job in LibreOffice.  I've tried the Mail Merge tool but that doesn't seem to do what I want.

What I'm doing is the create simple emails that say 'Hi ' and then include some further information in the body of the text. I'm quite happy to produce LibreOffice documents then copy and paste each into Gmail as a new email.

I've created a spreadsheet with the data in and registered it as a data source, like I would do for labels.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Mail_Merge_Wizard

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following method:

- Do Ctrl-F2 to bring up the Fields dialog
- Chose the Database tab, select Type 'Mail Merge fields'
- Under 'Database selection' select my spreadsheet and Sheet 1, then show its fields
- Put the cursor in the place I want a field, highlight the field and click Insert.
- When all fields inserted, save the changes.
- Got to the File menu and select Print. The procedure then is the same as for Labels

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of getting to use Mail merge in Libreoffice. @Tony listed one.

Another way is to start Tools-Mail Merge Wizard, which asks if that's a letter or e-mail, and also adds Address List. Mail Merge toolbar is open at the end of wizard, with which one can print or mail.
Addresses can be added also via File-Wizard-Address Data Source or set fields with Tools-Address Book Source.

My way is to add database (spreadsheet) via Edit-Exchange Database, then open View-Data Sources and drag fields where needed when creating a document, then Print or open Mail Merge toolbar to send e-mails (it can print too).

Prior to e-mailing, server must be set in Options-Writer-MM Email, but it will also be asked after clicking Send Email Messages.